# Optimizing list comprehension to find pairs of co-prime numbers

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension, greatest-common-divisor

> Given A,B print the number of pairs (a,b) such that GCD(a,b)=1 and 1<=a<=A and 1<=b<=B.

Here is my answer:

```
return len([(x,y) for x in range(1,A+1) for y in range(1,B+1) if gcd(x,y) == 1])
```

My answer works fine for small ranges but takes enough time if the range is increased.
such as

- 1 <= A <= 10^5
- 1 <= B <= 10^5

is there a better way to write this or can this be optimized?

Comment: Look up 'relatively prime'.

Comment: memoize your gcd function

Comment: Since you are doing the `gcd` check for a quadratic number of pairs, you should take the time to pre-calculate the prime-factor-sets for all the numbers; then finding out whether two numbers are co-prime is a simple matter of set-intersection.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: is that duplicate quite the same thing?  The fastest way to compute the number of pairs with a,b <= A, B that are relatively prime need not be coming up with a really fast way to check if two numbers are coprime and doing that lots of times.

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate, since this question is about testing _many_ pairs of numbers, thus there might be different algorithms to be considered.

Comment: @DSM: Hrm, I'll reopen, can't say I am 100% certain about the dupe, so  I better not have cast it.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. He has a legitimate algorithm, but needs to make it faster than O(n^2).

Comment: This question sounds familiar. Does the word codestorm ring a bell?

Comment: It does! thats the word that brought you here...didn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to calculate whether `gcd == 1` for each *pair* of numbers, you should pre-calculate all the prime factor sets. This way, you can later very quickly determine whether two numbers are coprime by checking the intersection of their prime factor sets. We can do this fast in a [sieve-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) approach.

```
factors = [set() for n in range(N)]
factored = collections.defaultdict(set)
for n in range(2, N):
    if not factors[n]:           # no factors yet -> n is prime
        for m in range(n, N, n): # all multiples of n up to N
            factors[m].add(n)
            factored[n].add(m)
```

After this, `factors[n]` will hold a set of all the prime factors of `n` (duh), and `factored[n]` all the numbers that *are* factored *by* `n`. This will come in handy now, since otherwise we would still need to check up to 10,000 x 10,000 pairs of numbers, which can still be rather slow in Python. But using the `factors` and `factored` sets in combination, we can now quickly find all the co-primes for a given number by eliminating the numbers that share a prime factor with `n`.

```
for n in range(1, N):
    coprimes = set(range(1, N))  # start with all the numbers in the range
    for f in factors[n]:         # eliminate numbers that share a prime factor
        coprimes -= factored[f]
    print "%d is coprime with %r others" % (n, len(coprimes))
```

For `N == 100` the result looks plausible to me, and for `N == 10000` it takes about 10 seconds on my computer. This might require some work to fit your actual problem, but I guess it's a good start.

Answer (score 3):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Generating_all_coprime_pairs) this should generate all coprimes:

```
from collections import deque

def coprimes():
    tree = deque([[2, 1], [3, 1]])
    while True:
        m, n = tree.popleft()
        yield m, n
        tree.append([2 * m - n, m])
        tree.append([2 * m + n, m])
        tree.append([m + 2 * n, n])
```

This is not the fastest algorithm, but the easiest to understand. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Answer (score 1):

I know that's an oldie, but since I needed something like that for another problem, and couldn't find something fast enough, here is a new answer. It takes `840ms` to list all (unordered) coprimes `(x, y)` s.t. `x < y <= 10,000`.

The idea is to first get a list of primes (using [`primesieve`](https://pypi.org/project/primesieve/)). Then, from that list, we construct all integers up to `N` using the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)). I presented the argument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70661056/758174):  we just need to iterate through all the possible products `prod(p_i**k_i)` where `p_i` is the `i^th` prime number and `k_i` is any non-negative integer.

The iterator `gen_prod_primes()` below conveniently returns the distinct primes that were used along with each integer. So we can just generate all coprimes of that integer by using all the other primes (the ones not used in making the first integer).

Putting it all together:

```py
from primesieve import primes

def rem_p(q, p, p_distinct):
    q0 = q
    while q % p == 0:
        q //= p
    if q != q0:
        if p_distinct[-1] != p:
            raise ValueError(f'rem({q}, {p}, ...{p_distinct[-4:]}): p expected at end of p_distinct if q % p == 0')
        p_distinct = p_distinct[:-1]
    return q, p_distinct

def add_p(q, p, p_distinct):
    if len(p_distinct) == 0 or p_distinct[-1] != p:
        p_distinct += (p, )
    q *= p
    return q, p_distinct

def gen_prod_primes(p, upto=None):
    if upto is None:
        upto = p[-1]
    if upto >= p[-1]:
        p = p + [upto + 1]  # sentinel
    
    q = 1
    i = 0
    p_distinct = tuple()
    
    while True:
        while q * p[i] <= upto:
            i += 1
        while q * p[i] > upto:
            yield q, p_distinct
            if i <= 0:
                return
            q, p_distinct = rem_p(q, p[i], p_distinct)
            i -= 1
        q, p_distinct = add_p(q, p[i], p_distinct)

def coprimes(upto):
    p = list(primes(upto))
    ps = set(p)
    for y, p_distinct in gen_prod_primes(p, upto):
        for x, _ in gen_prod_primes(list(ps - set(p_distinct)), upto=y):
            yield x, y
```

Now:

```py
>>> sorted(coprimes(6))
[(1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 5),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 5),
 (5, 6)]

%timeit list(coprimes(10_000))
840 ms ± 804 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# but time grows fast:
%timeit list(coprimes(20_000))
6.57 s ± 9.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit list(coprimes(30_000))
13.1 s ± 23.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> len(list(coprimes(10_000)))
1246336

>>> len(list(coprimes(20_000)))
9834865

>>> len(list(coprimes(30_000)))
19845763
```

Notes:

- the iterator yields coprimes unordered.
- the result is half all co-primes; just reverse each tuple to get the other half.