# How can I solve the error in this algorithm code (TypeError: 'NoneType' )?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm having trouble understanding and applying this exercise on my own with Python. I am getting this:

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

This is the exercise Algorithm:

> Definition: An integer is said to be perfect if it is equal to the sum
> of all its divisors. Examples: 6 and 28 are perfect since   6 = 1+2+3
> (knowing that 1, 2 and 3 are the divisors of 6 less than 6) 28=
> 1+2+4+7+14 (knowing that 1, 2, 4, 7 and 14 are the divisors of 28 less
> than 28)
>
> 1. Create a function liste_divisors(), which accepts an
>    integer N as a parameter and returns the list of its divisors less
>    than N (1 included).
> 2. Make a function is perfect(), which accepts a (positive) integer N
>    as a parameter and returns “True” if it is perfect and “False”
>    otherwise (use the function from the 1st question)
> 3. Create a Perfect List() function, which accepts a Limit parameter,
>    then returns a list containing the perfect numbers less than Limit

I'm having trouble with the last question

This is my attempt so far, but there are errors. How can I correct these errors?

```py
def liste_diviseur(N):
   t = []
   for i in range(1,N):
      if(N%i == 0):
         t.append(i)
   return t

def est_parfait(M):
   s = 0
   for i in liste_diviseur(M):
      s += i 
   if(s == M):
      return True
   else:
      return False

def liste_parfait(Limite):
   t = []
   lis = print(liste_diviseur(Limite))
   if(Limite<lis):
      t.append(Limite)
   return t
m = int(input('Giving an number :'))
print(liste_parfait(m))
```

Comment: lis = print(liste_diviseur(Limite)) returns a NoneType. Remove the print statement in that line

Comment: Dont work my friend

Comment: in general, python errors will tell you the line they happened on, and you can immediately narrow down what's happening to that line and the lines above. For instance, your error tells you that `Limite<lis` python thinks `lis` is `None`, so you look above to where `lis` is set and know that something's going wrong with that line. Just a helpful way to narrow your search for errors in the future.

Comment: Thanks my friend do you help me in quetion 3 please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a range and then check if each number in the range is perfect.

```
def liste_diviseur(n):
   return [i for i in range(1,n//2+1) if n%i==0]


def est_parfait(n):
   return n == sum(liste_diviseur(n))
         

def liste_parfait(limite): 
   return [i for i in range(2, limite) if est_parfait(i)]
   

test = int(input('Giving an number: '))
print(liste_parfait(test))
# output for 8129
[6, 28, 496, 8128]
```

Comment: Thank you very very much my friend mashallah elik

Comment: I removed my comment about perfect numbers being even, this is *probably* true, but not actually proven.

Comment: what ;y friend  ??

Answer (score 1):

Your error appears to be when you set `lis = print(liste_diviseur(Limite))`. print() is a void function which will return null. Removing the `print()` should fix your problem

Comment: Dont work my friend

Comment: @messidon do you get the same error, or a different one?

Comment: Please my friend solve question 3 because I did not know him

Comment: @messidon We have solved the original question on the post, but this isn't a forum for finishing your homework for you. I would recommend setting up a python debugger so you can see what each of those functions are returning and comparing them to what you expect. Hint: What type is liste_diviseur returning? What do you need to do with that information?

Comment: Sorry my friend

Answer (score 0):

The main part is generating the divisors. You can find some ideas for efficiency e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753839/efficiently-getting-all-divisors-of-a-given-number).

For large numbers, one would use factorization of `n` into its factors (see e.g. [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575747/758174) I wrote for another problem), and then generate all divisors by combining those factors.

Here, we'll go for simplicity:

```py
from math import isqrt

def divisors(n):
    m = isqrt(n)
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            j = n // i
            if i < j < n:
                yield n // i
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(divisors(36))
[1, 2, 18, 3, 12, 4, 9, 6]
```

Note that `divisors()` returns a generator, not a `list`, and the divisors are produced out of order (more precisely: as pairs `i` and `n // i`). But this doesn't matter to see if a number if perfect or not:

```py
def is_perfect(n):
    return sum(divisors(n)) == n

>>> is_perfect(5)
False

>>> is_perfect(6)
True
```

Now for a list of perfect numbers:

```py
>>> [n for n in range(1, 10_000) if is_perfect(n)]
[6, 28, 496, 8128]
```